# Extract GPS data from XML in R

Tags: r, xml, gps

I'm trying to analyse some GPS data in a .tcx file containing multiple laps. I want to do something very similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8280437/import-tcx-into-r-using-xml-package)
 - basically extract each trackpoint into a dataframe for further analysis. But I need to keep the information defining each lap.

I'm a complete xml novice - my failed attempts are below, along with an extract of my data. Note that the position data is missing as my GPS failed when I was creating the test data. Just pretend that each trackpoint contains lat and long as well.

```
library(XML)
library(plyr)
doc <- xmlInternalTreeParse("test.tcx")
doc
  <Lap>
    <Track>
      <Trackpoint>
        <Time>2017-05-03T08:22:56.000Z</Time>
        <SensorState>Present</SensorState>
      </Trackpoint>
      <Trackpoint>
        <Time>2017-05-03T08:22:57.000Z</Time>
        <SensorState>Present</SensorState>
      </Trackpoint>
      <Trackpoint>
        <Time>2017-05-03T08:22:58.000Z</Time>
        <SensorState>Present</SensorState>
      </Trackpoint>
      <Trackpoint>
        <Time>2017-05-03T08:22:59.000Z</Time>
        <SensorState>Present</SensorState>
      </Trackpoint>
      <Trackpoint>
        <Time>2017-05-03T08:23:00.000Z</Time>
        <SensorState>Present</SensorState>
      </Trackpoint>
      <Trackpoint>
        <Time>2017-05-03T08:23:01.000Z</Time>
        <SensorState>Present</SensorState>
      </Trackpoint>
    </Track>
  </Lap>
  <Lap>
    <Track>
       <Trackpoint>
        <Time>2017-05-03T08:23:02.000Z</Time>
        <SensorState>Present</SensorState>
      </Trackpoint>
      <Trackpoint>
        <Time>2017-05-03T08:23:03.000Z</Time>
        <SensorState>Present</SensorState>
      </Trackpoint>
      <Trackpoint>
        <Time>2017-05-03T08:23:04.000Z</Time>
        <SensorState>Present</SensorState>
      </Trackpoint>
      <Trackpoint>
        <Time>2017-05-03T08:23:05.000Z</Time>
        <SensorState>Present</SensorState>
      </Trackpoint>
      <Trackpoint>
        <Time>2017-05-03T08:23:06.000Z</Time>
        <SensorState>Present</SensorState>
      </Trackpoint>
      <Trackpoint>
        <Time>2017-05-03T08:23:07.000Z</Time>
        <SensorState>Present</SensorState>
      </Trackpoint>
    </Track>
  </Lap>

> nodes <- getNodeSet(doc, "//ns:Trackpoint", "ns")
> ldply(nodes, as.data.frame(xmlToList))
                  value.Time value.SensorState
1   2017-05-03T08:22:56.000Z           Present
2   2017-05-03T08:22:57.000Z           Present
3   2017-05-03T08:22:58.000Z           Present
4   2017-05-03T08:22:59.000Z           Present
5   2017-05-03T08:23:00.000Z           Present
6   2017-05-03T08:23:01.000Z           Present
7   2017-05-03T08:23:02.000Z           Present
...
```

Following the steps in that answer gets me 90% of the way there, as you can see, but I lose the lap information. I've tried splitting the data by lap/track (I've yet to work out when there's a  that isn't immediately preceded by , but that doesn't really matter), but then struggled to make it any further.

`nodes2 <- getNodeSet(doc, "//ns:Track", "ns")` successfully breaks the xml up by laps into something that looks similar to a list, but is of the class XMLNodeSet, and I then can't use `ldply` or `getNodeSet` on `nodes2`. I've played around with `xmlApply` and `xmlToList` but no luck.

I've also tried a bit of a botch using a loop, but have even had problems there. Seemingly `getNodeSet(nodes2[[i]],...)` performs the operation on all of the trackpoints contained in `nodes2` rather than just those in `nodes2[[i]]`.

```
test <- nodes2[[1]] 
#successfully pulls out just the 6 trackpoints in lap 1
ldply(getNodeSet(test,"//ns:Trackpoint", "ns"), as.data.frame(xmlToList))
#creates a dataframe containing all 18 trackpoints in `nodes`.
```

So I'm completely confused by that.

The other alternative is not to split the data up by laps but to have one big dataframe that with a factor variable for lap. The only way I can think of to do that would be such a botch that it makes gag a bit.

Any suggestions or nudges in the right direction greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance,

James

---

Update: turns out I made a hash of simplifying my input data and deleted some information that was needed. Chris S's solution works for the extract of data that I included originally, but there are some higher levels to the XML, `<TrainingCenterDatabase>`, `<Activities>` and `<Activity>`. Like I said, I'm a complete beginner. Here is the very start of another XML doc in the same format as the last.

```
<TrainingCenterDatabase>
    <Activities>
        <Activity Sport="Other">
            <Id>2017-05-11T08:27:04.000Z</Id>
            <Lap StartTime="2017-05-11T08:27:05.000Z">
                <TotalTimeSeconds>106.0</TotalTimeSeconds>
                <DistanceMeters>157.1999969482422</DistanceMeters>
                <MaximumSpeed>1.6944444179534912</MaximumSpeed>
                <Calories>20</Calories>
                <Intensity>Active</Intensity>
                <TriggerMethod>Manual</TriggerMethod>
                <Track>
                    <Trackpoint>
                        <Time>2017-05-11T08:27:05.000Z</Time>
                        <Position>
                            <LatitudeDegrees>51.50305517</LatitudeDegrees>
                            <LongitudeDegrees>-0.09115383</LongitudeDegrees>
                        </Position>
                        <DistanceMeters>1.6944444179534912</DistanceMeters>
                        <SensorState>Present</SensorState>
                    </Trackpoint>
                    <Trackpoint>
                        <Time>2017-05-11T08:27:06.000Z</Time>
                        <Position>
                            <LatitudeDegrees>51.50305517</LatitudeDegrees>
                            <LongitudeDegrees>-0.09115383</LongitudeDegrees>
                        </Position>
                        <DistanceMeters>3.3888888359069824</DistanceMeters>
                        <SensorState>Present</SensorState>
                    </Trackpoint>
```

On the plus side, I've got the output to include an attribute under Lap for StartTime, which can be what goes into the final dataframe. I think all that needs adjusting is

```
xpathSApply(doc, "//Trackpoint/..", xmlSize)
```

Comment: What is your desired output? *I lose the Lap information* ... what info as the Lap nodes carry no attribute or text by itself?

Comment: @Parfait By lap information, I just mean "which lap was I on at this point? 1, 2, 3 etc?"

Answer (score 1):

This should get your trackpoint data...

```
x <- xmlToDataFrame(doc["//Trackpoint"])
```

If you need to add values or attributes from a parent node to that table, then get the size of the parent node (6 and 6) and repeat the attribute or value (since you have neither, I repeated numbers).

```
n <- xpathSApply(doc, "//Lap/Track", xmlSize) #OR
n <- xpathSApply(doc, "//Trackpoint/..", xmlSize)
# if Lap had an attribute 
x$Lap <- rep( xpathSApply(doc, "//Lap", xmlGetAttr, "number"), n)
x$Lap <- rep( 1:length(n), n)
x
                       Time SensorState Lap
1  2017-05-03T08:22:56.000Z     Present   1
2  2017-05-03T08:22:57.000Z     Present   1
3  2017-05-03T08:22:58.000Z     Present   1
4  2017-05-03T08:22:59.000Z     Present   1
5  2017-05-03T08:23:00.000Z     Present   1
6  2017-05-03T08:23:01.000Z     Present   1
7  2017-05-03T08:23:02.000Z     Present   2
8  2017-05-03T08:23:03.000Z     Present   2
...
```

Comment: Thanks, hadn't thought of pulling out the size of the parent node. Looks like it should sort the problem, expect an upvote once I've tried it out.

Comment: So your solution works on the extract of data I gave, but it turns out I'd made a foul up when taking the subset. I've added an update to the question, would hugely appreciate it if you could take another look and offer anymore advice. Thanks, James

Comment: I would post another question.  `xmlToDataFrame` only works with simple XML structures, the workaround I mentioned works in very limited cases, but now you have a very complex file and there are a number of possible solutions.

Comment: Yep, I think a new question's the way to go. I managed to find a workaround by extracting the times at which each lap was triggered and working out which lap each trackpoint must have been on, but it feels a bit like cheating given the whole point was teach myself XML.